# How do you set the default counters running when you start perfmon?

Tags: windows, performance, system, administration

When you start perfmon*, it loads running 3 counters: Memory "Pages/sec", Physical Disk "Disk Queue length" and Processor "% Processor Time".

How can I change that to be counters I care about?

*To start perfmon, either type "perfmon" at a command prompt or under "Administrative Tools" select "Performance"

Comment: Personally, I always run perfmon with "/sys" argument so it starts without any counters loaded.

Comment: How did you learn about using /sys? I would if I can use that to track down my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run "perfmon /sys", add the counters you like, go to "File / Save Settings As" which saves a .PerfmonCfg file.

Now you can either launch the file directly from explorer or load it from perfmon using "File / Load Settings".

OS version note: This assumes Windows 7. This feature is not available for Windows XP.

Comment: Add version of Windows are you using? I have Windows XP. The File menu does not have Save Settings As

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using Windows 7. Don't know when it started being an option, as I've just found out about this yesterday.

Comment: I edited the answer just to clarify it assumes Win 7. I set your answer as THE answer.